# inject script inside iframe of different domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, inject

i was trying to inject script inside an iframe element trying to implement this way,
child and parent does not belong to same domain (i know XSS is prevented in latest browsers)
is there any way to inject script to child element of button click on parent element.
(kinda similar running scripts in chrome console)

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById("myIframeId");
var script = myIframe.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "randomshit.js";
myIframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: No, the cross domain origin policy prohibits this. The pages can communicate using messages though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) dates back to Netscape 2.0.

Unless you can hack/XSS the other site's files to inject the JS, you will have a hard time.

Now if you legitimately need to communicate with the other page, and you either have control of the other page or can setup it to communicate with your server, you can use [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage), [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067472/1331430) or even Ajax with CORS (latter 2 will be harder to pass dynamic content though). But I believe it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

using chrome extension add this to manifest
`{ "matches": ["<all_urls>"], "all_frames": true, "js": ["captcha.js"] }`
and using console you can use this:
`var firstIframe = window.frames[0];
console.log(firstIframe);

// Access the contentDocument of the iframe
var iframeDocument = firstIframe.document;

// Use jQuery within the iframe to select '.img-action-text' elements
var elements = $(iframeDocument).find('.img-action-text');`